# Use ng-blur on md-autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I wish to build a simple editable input-bar in angular material, when I click the high-light text, it will open a `md-autocomplete`, and if I click outside part, it will close the `md-autocomplete` and show the text.

```
<div ng-hide="vm.editableEnabled" ng-click="vm.enableEditorTitle()">
    <span class="hight-light">{{vm.group.name}}</span>
</div>

<md-autocomplete ng-show="vm.editableEnabled"
....
....
ng-blur="vm.disableEditorTitle()">
</md-autocomplete>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXvhX8CoBELX3uqeUk1T?p=info)

But the `ng-blur` does not work in `md-autocomplete`.

I know this is a issue in https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3906. 
I have tried the directive solution but it does not work.

It there any other good solution to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: see this https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3906 and https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3357

Comment: I have tried the directive solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest, if md-blur doesn't work in md-autocomplete and your div element containing md-autocomplete is isolated enough..Give a try to bind the method "vm.disableEditorTitle()"  on click of div's body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Added a directive** called `onClickOutside`, it will **trigger an expression** when a **clicked outside** of his nested items.

In addition, note that **you can spare the functions** in your controller by directly changing `vm.editableEnabled = true/false`

---

**Online Demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/5NlWD2bXFkGPXuj0Awav?p=preview**

[image]

```
<div on-click-outside="vm.editableEnabled = false">
  <div ng-hide="vm.editableEnabled" ng-click="vm.editableEnabled = true" ... >
  <md-autocomplete ng-show="vm.editableEnabled" ... >
</div>
```

javascript:

```
.directive('onClickOutside', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        onClickOutside: "&"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        angular.element(document).bind('click', function(event) {
          var isChild = childOf(event.target, element[0]);
          if (!isChild) {
            scope.$apply(scope.onClickOutside);
          }

        });

        function childOf(c, p) {
          while ((c = c.parentNode) && c !== p);
          return !!c;
        }
      }

    };

  });
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cna use the md-search-text-change attribute